# Walmart product search api

Tags: walmart-api

I have one question when search product using walmart api.I get response but i want to need some detail of their property. what is meaning following properties name which is get in response of walmart search api.

- productTrackingUrl
- addToCartUrl
- affiliateAddToCartUrl
- productUrl

> productTrackingUrl & affiliateAddToCartUrl return error somethink like that "The link you clicked on is malformed. Contact the editor of the originating page."

Comment: Do you have the documentation of Wal-Mart API?

Comment: Here is link https://developer.walmartlabs.com/docs @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: Please [edit] the title of your question to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. The current title is pretty meaningless, as you've already tagged the question as *walmart-api*. The title should be descriptive enough to have meaning for a future site user who is scanning a list of search results trying to find a solution to their problem. Thanks.